# Cannot change current Displayable using setCurrent

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I am creating a java ME app that uses bluetooth.

No matter how I try to change the current `Displayable` it does not change.

My app sets a textbox called "devices" as the current displayable in startup and I change current to a list called "devicelist" in a method in another class.

But when I try to change the current back to textbox (devices ) it doesn't change.

I tried using the display object in midlet class and also using gestDisplay in other class. But the List object (deviceList) remains the current Displayable.

**update** Per my testing, there seems to be some bug. The TextBox (devices) is the current Displayable but when I check `isShown` it comes as false. Instead the other Displayable: List (deviceList) when tested with `isShown` comes as true.
Although the api specifications suggest that `setCurrent` method's effect is not immediate, the current Displayable is changing but it is not shown on the screen.And this happens both in the real device and the emulator.

Comment: if you properly obtain Display object in the instance of your MIDlet class, in startApp - then setCurrent should do what you expect. Your issue is because you've got bugs in your code. Add logging, test, study logs when things go wrong, add more logging and re-test until you get rid of bugs

Comment: yes thats how i got to know that current does not change.And also i see no exceptions.What would be the best way to create logs except make something print in current.?
Sorry i'm new to the forum. Shall i post the code here?

Comment: if you test with emulator, the simplest way is to use `System.out.println` to trace midlet execution in the console. There are also various logging libraries for Java ME worth considering for testing with real devices, but for emulator system.out.println is just fine

Comment: cannot test with emulator as the app requires to discover a bluetooth service and this service is provided by my pc and a java me device cannot rpovide the services.
Sorry, actually i can test this part because it does not require the service. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: I see - in that case, search tags ["java-me plus logging"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-me+logging "search URL") for suggestions for on-device debugging. Although there is a good chance that bug is in midp-only code and you would find it much easier by [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object "what's this?") bluetooth-related parts of midlet for emulator testing

Comment: @gnat shall i paste the code here or to a pastebin?

Comment: having code in pastebin is not quite welcome at Stack Overflow. Preferred way here is to add relevant code snippets or, better yet, [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example)](http://www.sscce.org/ "detailed explanation") into the question

Answer (score 1):

You found one right part of specification but not all of them - that's why you are confused.

Your understanding that *setCurrent method's effect is not immediate* is 100% right indeed, that's what API javadocs specify, OK:

- [Display.setCurrent(Displayable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#setCurrent%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable%29):

> <sup>...The change will typically not take effect immediately. It may be delayed so that it occurs between event delivery method calls, although it is not guaranteed to occur before the next event delivery method is called. The setCurrent() method returns immediately, without waiting for the change to take place...</sup>
>   
>   Now, your note that *the current Displayable is changing but it is not shown* makes me feel that you use `getCurrent` and expect it to reliably tell when screen is shown. This is not so, take a look at API docs:

- [Display.getCurrent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#getCurrent%28%29):

> <sup>Gets the current Displayable object for this MIDlet... object returned may not actually be visible... The [Displayable.isShown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Displayable.html#isShown%28%29) method may be called to determine whether the Displayable is actually visible on the display.</sup>
>   
>   So, the simple answer would likely be to use `isShown()` (instead of getCurrent) to find out when needed screen becomes visible. Although...

...the fact that you're experiencing delays and especially that this happens even on emulator, makes me feel that there may be design problem in your midlet. I would **strongly** recommend to check whether there is some "heavyweight" activity that you run in the same thread as UI, blocking it and making it irresponsive.

Avoid heavy load in UI event thread. When there's much to do of something inside of `commandAction` or `keyPressed` or `pointerPressed` etc, just spawn a new thread to do that. If you find this to be the case in your midlet, consider studying this tutorial to find out tow to do it right:

- [Networking, User Experience, and Threads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/threading-155506.html)

> <sup>This article explains how your MIDlet can make network connections without compromising your user interface. It includes six iterative examples that illustrate multithreaded networking and the use of a wait screen...</sup>